# Why is the loop not looping?

Tags: php, html, loops

So I'm learning PHP, and as such, was attempting to create a programme to simplify fractions (a very beginner's code, to say the least). It uses an HTML form, from which it pulls the numerator and the denominator. However, upon form submission, the functions spit out the inputted numbers. My thought is that it is passing over the 'for' loop in each function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS for echoed data -->
    <style>
        p {
        text-size:12px;
        text-color:black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Defines Form -->
    <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        Numerator: <br />
        <input type = "text" name = "numOne"><br />
        Denominator: <br />
        <input type = "text" name = "numTwo"><br />
        <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Reduce!">

    </form>
<?php

//Executes task upon form submission 
        if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
            $n1 = $_POST['numOne'];
            $n2 = $_POST['numTwo'];
//Defines numerator simplification function
            function simplifynum ($n1,$n2) {
                $n1 = $_POST['numOne'];
                $n2 = $_POST['numTwo'];
                if ($n1 < $n2){
//Loops until numerator and denominator are reduced to simplest form                    
                    for ($x = 2;$x < $n2;$x++){
                        $divedn1 = ($n1 / $x);
                        $divedn2 = ($n2 / $x);
//If all divided values are purely digits (i.e. are whole numbers) and not equal to zero, sets new numerator and denominators variables to the divided value
                        if (ctype_digit($divedn1) && ctype_digit($divedn2) && ($divedn1 != 0) && ($divedn2 != 0)) {
                            $n1 = $divedn1;
                            $n2 = $divedn2;
                        }
                    }
//returns numerator data
                    return $n1;
                }
            }
//Defines denominator simplification function           
            function simplifyden ($n1,$n2) {
                $n1 = $_POST['numOne'];
                $n2 = $_POST['numTwo'];
                if ($n1 < $n2){
//Loops until numerator and denominator are reduced to simplest form
                    for ($x = 2;$x < $n2;$x++){
                        $divedn1 = ($n1 / $x);
                        $divedn2 = ($n2 / $x);
//If all divided values are purely digits (i.e. are whole numbers) and not equal to zero, sets new numerator and denominators variables to the divided value
                        if ( ctype_digit($divedn1) && ctype_digit($divedn2) && ($divedn1 != 0) && ($divedn2 != 0)) {
                            $n1 = $divedn1;
                            $n2 = $divedn2;
                        }
                    }
//returns denominator data
                    return $n2;
                }
            }






    ?>
    <!-- Runs functions and reads respective values -->
    <p><?php echo simplifynum($n1, $n2);?><br /> &#9473;<br /><?php echo simplifyden($n1, $n2);?></p>
    <?php 
//Unsets form submission
            unset($_POST['Submit']);
        }

    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: why a function for each component of the fraction?

Comment: The `ctype_digit` function expects a string. Passing in an integer assumes that is the ascii number for a single character. [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php#refsect1-function.ctype-digit-notes) says this in the "notes" section. In your case here, you could use [is_int](https://php.net/is_int) to check if you have a whole number or you can skip the division and whole number check using the modulus operator `%` which returns the remainder of a division. So `25 % 5 = 0` because 25 is evenly divisible by 5 and `26 % 5 = 1`. When evenly divisible, you will get zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is to simplify fractions because the rule is that the two numbered components and denominator must be divisible by the same digit to be correct, you do not need two functions and also collect by post method for each function when you are already sent such as parameter values to the function.

try this

```
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    Numerator: <br />
    <input type = "text" name = "numOne"><br />
    Denominator: <br />
    <input type = "text" name = "numTwo"><br />
    <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Reduce!">

</form>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $n1 = $_POST['numOne'];
        $n2 = $_POST['numTwo'];
        simplifynum($n1, $n2);//call the function


}
        function simplifynum ($n1,$n2) {
            $menor = 0;
            if ($n1 < $n2){ $menor= $n1;} 
            else {$menor=$n2;}//I check less variable to find the maximum number of digit in the divisor for and not have decimal results

                for ($x = 2;$x < $menor;){ //Start the divisor digit two
                   if($n1 % $x == 0 && $n2 % $x==0) //Seeking the digit that is divisible for two numbers by modulo operation% to return the waste if zero is because it is divisible
                   {
                        $n1 = $n1/$x; //I check with the first number
                        $n2 = $n2/$x; //I check the second number
                   }
                  else
                    $x= $x+1;//if the two numbers not divisible increase as the variable in this case would be 3, the first iteration
                }

                echo $n1  . " /" . $n2  . "<br/>";
                echo  "Result  : " . ($n1/$n2);
            }

?>
```

Comment: It would probably be more helpful if you talked about the changes you have made to the function like using modulus.

Comment: I hadn't thought of modulus before, that solved the issue! Thank you! I guess I still have a few more things to learn with PHP haha.